# jQueryでユニークIDを追加後に中の特定要素を削除したい

Tags: javascript, jquery

繰り返しコンテンツ（実際は複数ある`input`要素ですが、テストの為）を挿入するボタンを使いたいのですが、`display:none`の要素をpart-oneとpart-twoに分けて表示させたいのですが、ユニークで生成されたidの場合、``` $(newId > .part-one)``$(newId > .part-two) ```のように指定できますでしょうか？

```js
var total = 1;
var content = $('#content');

function add(type) {

  if (type === 'one') {
    var newId = 'content_' + total;
    var clonedContent = content.clone().attr('id', newId);
    //part-twoのみ削除
    clonedContent.insertBefore(content);
  } else {
    var newId = 'content_' + total;
    var clonedContent = content.clone().attr('id', newId);
    //part-oneのみ削除
    clonedContent.insertBefore(content);
  }
  total++;
}
```

```css
#content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="add('one')">one</button>
<button onclick="add('two')">two</button>

<div id="content">
  <div class="part-one">
    this is part-one
  </div>
  <div class="part-two">
    this is part-two
  </div>
  <div class="part-one">
    this is part-one
  </div>
  <div class="part-two">
    this is part-two
  </div>
  <div class="part-one">
    this is part-one
  </div>
  <div class="part-two">
    this is part-two
  </div>
  <div class="part-one">
    this is part-one
  </div>
  <div class="part-two">
    this is part-two
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`children()`と`remove()`を組み合わせることで実現できます。

```js
var total = 1;
var content = $('#content');

function add(type) {

  if (type === 'one') {
    var newId = 'content_' + total;
    var clonedContent = content.clone().attr('id', newId);
    clonedContent.children('.part-two').remove();
    clonedContent.insertBefore(content);
  } else {
    var newId = 'content_' + total;
    var clonedContent = content.clone().attr('id', newId);
    clonedContent.children('.part-one').remove();
    clonedContent.insertBefore(content);
  }
  total++;
}
```

```css
#content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="add('one')">one</button>
<button onclick="add('two')">two</button>

<div id="content">
  <div class="part-one">
    this is part-one
  </div>
  <div class="part-two">
    this is part-two
  </div>
  <div class="part-one">
    this is part-one
  </div>
  <div class="part-two">
    this is part-two
  </div>
  <div class="part-one">
    this is part-one
  </div>
  <div class="part-two">
    this is part-two
  </div>
  <div class="part-one">
    this is part-one
  </div>
  <div class="part-two">
    this is part-two
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: 有難うございます。
`children()`の場合は直下にある要素のみに適応しているのですね。正に求めていた解答です。大変勉強になりました。

Answer (score 1):

`input`が複数あるとのことなので`if`文をなくしてシンプルかつ拡張性のある形にしました。

```js
var total = 1;
var content = $('#content');

function add(type) {

  var addContent = $('<div>').attr('id', 'content_' + total);

  addContent.html(content.find('.part-' + type));
  addContent.insertBefore(content);

  total++;
}
```

```css
#content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="add('one')">one</button>
<button onclick="add('two')">two</button>

<div id="content">
  <div class="part-one">this is part-one</div>
  <div class="part-two">this is part-two</div>
  <div class="part-one">this is part-one</div>
  <div class="part-two">this is part-two</div>
  <div class="part-one">this is part-one</div>
  <div class="part-two">this is part-two</div>
  <div class="part-one">this is part-one</div>
  <div class="part-two">this is part-two</div>
</div>
```